# Convert a passing SSRS Report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

I'm having an issue with a monthly report linking to a weekly report. The month parameter is passed through, however the weekly report does not allow that value for the parameter and results in an error. Since there is no monthly data, I do not want to show that value from the dropdown, but I would like the parameter to result in the display of a text that notifies the visitor that no monthly data is present and additionally show the weekly report.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement that feature?

Thnx!

Comment: Did you add try adding a parameter and set it to intern to avoid dropdown selector? Also you should allow the parameter takes blank or null values based on the data type. When the parameter would be populated?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try this next week! Thanks